# Render React From Go Server

Tags: reactjs, go, webpack, server

I am currently rendering a webpack build file (bundle.js) through a Go server.
How can I make my build files hot reload, or what do I need to do in order to serve hot reload files from the Go server?

When I use the 'npm run start' script, I am told that the webpack output is served from 
http://localhost:3000/dist/

and the project output is from 
http://localhost:3000

My directory is as follows

```
+ public
  - bundle.js
+ src
  - App.js
  - index.js
- index.html
- package.json
- server.go
- webpack.config.js
```

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>React Starter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <script src="/public/bundle.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

// webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    publicPath: "/public/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "r-proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "a": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --hot --inline"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  }
}
```

// server.go

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("./index.html")
  t.Execute(w, "")
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/"))

  http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public", fs)) 

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Go and its standard lib doesn't provide a ready made solution for hot reload. You will have to look for 3rd party packages if you want hot reload with your go server. The first result from google points to https://github.com/cosmtrek/air if that doesn't suit your needs you'll have to search the internet a bit more.

Comment: I am currently serving the /public/bundle.js output file.
Do you know if its possible to serve the devserver output specified at /dist?
That way I could use React's hot reloading?

Comment: You can serve `/dist` with go of course, create a file server handler and then register it, just like you do with the `/public` one. However this will not hot reload you browser automatically on change, you'll have to refresh the page manually, or use a 3rd party package as already suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: So that's what I'm having trouble with.  Can you tell me which changes need to be made to webpack and my server.go file in order to serve from /dist because it's not able to find the file.

Comment: How are you accessing you web app? On which port?

Comment: Webpack dev server hosts it on 3000

Comment: But your go server is running on port 8080, your go server is serving files from the `public` folder to which the webpack **build output** is saved, if i'm reading the config correctly. Ergo try accessing you web app on port 8080. And make sure you don't ignore the error from `template.ParseFiles`.